# restrict dynamically loaded SWF module to only communicate with "master" module in flash and AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security, air

I want to have a "master" SWF module (kinda like "browser") load untrusted 3rd party SWF modules and let them call its public methods. But I don't want untrusted modules to communicate with each other, such as calling each others' methods. I also don't want to let untrusted SWFs access the stage or other global (?) objects, e.g. to prevent them from messing with the "browser"'s ui.

Let's consider the following situations:

(1) untrusted SWFs loaded from a single remote web server with single 2nd level domain; but potentially the server could be directed to generate separate 3rd level domains for each SWF like http:// swf123.server.com

(2) untrusted SWFs loaded from files by AIR application

Question: can my goal be achieved in either of these cases? If yes, how to go about that? How does the "application domains" and other flash security functionality map onto these situations?